# Protractor page object and element.all

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I want my element.all() to return children with prototyped methods.

here's my code so far:

```
el.tags = function() {
  var el = element.all(by.css('.tags > span'));
  // return el;
  return el.map(function(tag) {
    tag.name = function() {
      return tag.element(by.binding('tag.name')).getText()
    }

    tag.count = function() {
      var text = tag.element(by.binding('tag.count')).getText()
      return _.parseInt(text);
    }

    return tag;
  });

}
```

the idea being once I call `tags()` the children have my prototyped methods immediately.

```
var tags = tags().filter(function(tag) {
  return tag.name() === "foobar";
});
```

thanks!

Comment: Is the code you provided working? If not, please post the error(s) and the traceback.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? My guess is that there's a better approach to your problem. Otherwise the code above won't work because `getText()` returns a promise.